# "If, however in advance one has knowledge..." vs "However, if in advance one has knowledge..."

Tags: phrases, expressions, syntactic-analysis, sentence-starts, however-placement

I am trying to write a paper and and I am not sure of the correct phrasing of a particular sentence. Here is what I am currently using

> If, however, in advance one has knowledge of the material parameters
>   , then one may be able to determine a more efficient method.

Does the start of this sentence sound correct or should the sentence be -

> However, if in advance one has knowledge of the material parameters ,
>   then one may be able to determine a more efficient method.

Which form of the sentence is more appropriate? Or are they both equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

The most prominent problem with your sentence is the placement of "in advance", not "however". "However" can be placed pretty much anywhere, although if you put it after if, I'd enclose it with commas from both sides:

> If, however, one has knowledge of the material parameters *in advance*, then ...

Or

> However, if one has knowledge of the material paremters *in advance*, ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider them nearly equivalent--both about equally clumsy.

I'd prefer something like this:

> With advance knowledge of the material parameters, however, one may determine a more efficient method.

or, if allowed more liberty in rephrasing:

> Advance knowledge of the material parameters may lead to a more efficient method.